# Relative path in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, filepath, usb-drive

I have created a batch file that launches several programs at once.
I have since loaded the overall program on a USB using xampp - and am trying to get this batch file more dynamic as the drive letter may change based on the computer the usb is in.

I have located several answers to similar questions that point to %~dp0 being the correct answer to create a relative path to the programs I want to run. But I cannot get it working.  I have tried several combinations and they all say they cannot find the program the batch file is referring to.
Here is what I have for that portion of the batch file:

```
:: Start programs
cd "%~dp0/ic/"
start xampp_start.exe
cd "%~dp0/ic/"
start xampp-control.exe
cd "%~dp0/ic/"
start GoogleChromePortable.exe  http://localhost:8080/wordpress/
```

And my file structure is:
USB/IC/launch.bat

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: 1. Use a backslash (\\) to separate the components of a path. 2. `%~dp0` already contains trailing backslash.  Therefore, use `cd "%~dp0ic\"`.

Comment: Using %~dp0 is not creating a relative path.  That is an absolute path.  A relative path is a path to where the current working directory is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.
For those with similar problems.

I discovered the problem partly was due to Xampp itself, but was able to get these programs to launch by doing this:

```
:: Start programs
cd "%~dp0/"
start xampp_start.exe
cd "%~dp0/"
start xampp-control.exe
cd "%~dp0/GoogleChromePortable/"
start GoogleChromePortable.exe  http://localhost:8080/wordpress/
```

I misunderstood the role of %~dp0 and didn't realize it goes off the directory of the bat file.
thanks again.

Comment: Get rid of the forward slashes.  They are not needed.  Why are your doing a CD to the location of the batch file.  The working directory should already be the location of the batch file.  You do not need to do a change directory at all.  You can launch the program using the relative path of the batch file in two different ways 1: `start "" "GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe"` 2: `start "" /D "GoogleChromePortable" "GoogleChromePortable.exe"`.